# Auto tagging when using entity referencing

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities

I use the Entity reference module to link nodes of different content type to each other. In my case, node (A) references node (B).  B can be referenced by multiple A. Both A and B are tagged by the same taxonomy vocabulary. A is only tagged with one term.

I would like to automatically tag B with the same taxonomy term as A. How can this best be achieved?